# Android Java - is there an easy way to inflate Views in several rows?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, inflate

I'm quite new to programming so don't downvote me , please.
I need to inflate views like the text goes into TextView - when one line ends, text goes from the beginning of another, so my inflated Views should iflate from the beginning of screen(ViewGroup) and go under previous line of views. As usual text does.

The way I see it - I have sort of root vertical LinearLayout, then I place horisontal LinearLayout in it, calculate screen's width , calculate my view's width, inflate as many as my first LinearLayout can hold and make another horizontal LinearLayout where I place another line of views and repeat this until all of my views are inflated.

But may be there is some easier way? because here is quite too much to do for such a simple thing

Comment: You do realize that you can have multiple rows in a TextView?

Comment: I made an example of TextView - I want to Inflate my views on the screen the same way TextView operates with characters. If you just inflate 17 ImageViews into horizontal LinearLayout - you will probably see 6-7 of them, and I want my views to be inflated the way TextView place characters - in several rows

Answer (score 0):

How I would go about this, is having a static amount of images in each "row" which indeed are Horizontal LinearLayouts nested inside a Vertical LinearLayout (which maybe is nested inside a ScrollView?).

Say you choose to have 4 images/line, you're concerned that on different screen sizes they would have too much or too little padding and the outcome would not look nice? Since you are new to programming I'll introduce you to one of the things you probably are not familiar with in Android.

Your Project -> Res folder has a layout folder which contains the activity_main.xml

Create new folders inside the res folder called:
layout-sw320dp
layout-sw320dp-mdpi
layout-sw320dp-hdpi
layout-sw320dp-xhdpi
layout-sw480dp
layout-sw600dp
layout-sw600dp-mdpi
layout-sw720dp
layout-sw800dp

The folders above are just examples of what folders you can create.
For example the layout-sw600dp-mdpi contains the layout files for a phone that's screen's "smallest width is 600dp and has a medium dpi." Smallest width means either the vertical or horizontal width, which-ever happens to be smaller.

Lets say the phone you are using would natively use the "layout-sw720dp" folder for its layout but you dont have the folder in your project. Then the layout-folder the phone would use in this case is the layout-sw600dp-mdpi. The application will always use the "best/closest" layout the application supports.

So first step is to choose which layout folders you want to provide. And the second step is to copy/paste your layout files from the default layout-folder to all of the other layout-folders. After this you can start setting different Sizes and Paddings/Margins for your Components, be they Images or Layouts or whatever.

Always remember to set your Values in 'dp' instead of 'px' and font sizes in 'sp'.

I hope I could be of help.

Comment: well ..the answer I've found is as simple as GridView - it can add views in next rows

Comment: user2976267 Say you have 3 columns and x amount of rows. You would still have to specify the size for the images for different screen sizes. Grid View is better than nesting Linear Layouts though.